# How to install lmapm for lua?

Tags: lua

I am making a script that requires [lmapm](https://github.com/LuaDist/lmapm), but I'm not quite sure how to install it. I have 4 files,

```
lmapm.c
test.lua
README
Makefile
```

And I'm not sure how to use them in my lua environment. Lua 5.1 is installed on my desktop in a folder called "5.1", and it was installed with LuaRocks (If that matters) I know lua libraries are used with require, but this is a c file, not a lua file.

How can I install/use lmapm in my lua programs?

Upon reading the readme it tells me to run make, but makefile is just a "file" on my computer, there is nothing I can run it with.

Comment: `lmapm` is available in the LuaRocks repository, so a `luarocks install lmapm MAPM_INCDIR=... MAPM_LIBDIR=...` (insert the correct paths) should do it.

Comment: Are you running Windows or Linux or Mac OS X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **README**: Short description of what you got and how to install & use the module at the end.
- **test.lua**: Lua script to test the module/sample of usage.
- **lmapm.c**: C source code and the module in raw/still unusable form. Needs to get compiled and linked to a dynamic library of target platform.
- **Makefile**: Automatic build instructions to compile&link *lmapm.c* to what you finally use in Lua.

**Makefile** serves as a macro which makes building easier with minimal input by users. To run this file, you need program **make** (comes with GNU toolchain; on Unix install package `build-essential`, on Windows [MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/msys)). Before you have to fix the path to your Lua and MAPM installation (as mentioned in the official [build instructions](http://webserver2.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/install.html#building)). Furthermore you need the [C compiler and linker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection) (which you already installed on Unix together with **make** and have to install on Windows by f.e. [MinGW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW)).

The result is a dynamic library/Lua C module which you can `require` simply by its filename. To put it in the scope of Lua, move it in the application or (better) in the Lua modules directory.